# Extjs 5 - static function call other static function from same class

Tags: extjs, static-methods, extjs5

I have code like this:

```
Ext.define( 'someClass', {

   statics : {

      methodA   : function( ) { return 'A'; },
      methodAB  : function( ) {

        var A = this.methodA();
        return A + 'B';
      }
   }
} );
```

I have problem with accessing static `methodA`.
Can someone help me what would be a proper way to do it ?

Comment: You have a typo: it should be `function` instead of `funcyion`.

Comment: What do you mean you have a problem? https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/m7p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should call statics using the fully qualified className.methodName() syntax.  'this' inside a static is not going to be what you think it is.  For example, if called from an event handler it will probably be the 'window' object, which certainly doesn't have a methodA() method.  In other cases 'this' may be the prototype.  In that case you may get away with this syntax but it is misleading and likely to cause future bugs.